# Looking for the name of the meeting that anticipates system failure during feature design

Tags: process

In my organization, we often have meetings to discuss potential points of system failure, prior to implementing much / any of the actual code.  This helps us to identify points of architecture, and define test cases.  We incorrectly call this "GameDay."

I see project management has the term "premortem" which identifies faults in the *project plan,* but I am looking for a similar term for the system design / engineering related meeting.  Does this have a name?  Should it also be "premortem?"

Comment: A "premortem" sounds like a pretty reasonable term for any activity that tries to pre-empt failure.

Comment: Does "every meeting I've ever had with management" count?

Answer (score 2):

[FMEA - Failure Modes and Effects Analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_mode_and_effects_analysis).

> **Failure mode and effects analysis (FMEA;** often written with "failure modes" in plural) is the process of reviewing as many components, assemblies, and subsystems as possible to identify potential failure modes in a system and their causes and effects
>
> ...
>
> A successful FMEA activity helps identify potential failure modes based on experience with similar products and processes—or based on common physics of failure logic. It is widely used in development and manufacturing industries in various phases of the product life cycle. *Effects analysis* refers to studying the consequences of those failures on different system levels.

Quite common in the industry.

Comment: I linked to the Wikipedia article about this and quoted some of the text. If this isn't what you meant, feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - You did well, thank you.